# put a where in Sum clause in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sum

hi guys im using this MYSQL query to get the top uploader users and the total of thier images views in the current month :

```
$current_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of this month")) . ' 23:59:59';        
$users = DB::query("SELECT * ,
      COUNT(p.id) as numPics,
      SUM(p.views) as totalViews

    FROM
      images p 
    INNER JOIN
      users u
    ON
      p.user_id = u.id
     WHERE 
     p.created_at >= \"$current_month\"
    GROUP BY p.user_id
    ORDER BY totalViews DESC LIMIT 10");
```

the trouble that the totalViews return the total of views of all pictures of each user , what i want is to get the total of views of the pics uploaded in the current month of each user . thanks .

Comment: Looks like your `images.views` field is a simple count of all views for that image. Unless you're keeping track of when each view occurred, you won't be able to get the image views by month.

Comment: @imthepitts hmm given that the `p.create_at` must be this month that's not an issue.

Comment: @Hamza, if you're getting total views of all pictures for each user, then there are two possibilities: (1) All the users in your result set only have pictures created in the current month, or (2) your `images.created_at` field is being updated after initial created date.

Comment: Your date arithmetic is going to filter out any upload on the first day of the month, except for uploads occurring in the very last second of that day. It's not clear that's what you want.